# Constructor vs casting operator

Tags: c++, type-casting, constructors, explicit

I'm programming a library (so I have complete access to all the mentioned classes). Two classes (`A` and `B`) are essentially the same and differ only by their implementation, so they can easily be converted into one another.
But I'm asking myself, if converting by passing an argument of type `B` to one of `A`'s constructors or by implicitly casting `B` into `A`, is preferable. Two code examples to illustrate:

Using casting:

```
class A
{
public:
    int c[3];
    operator B() const
    {
        //return B(...);
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    int a, b, c;
    operator A() const
    {
        //return A(...);
    }
};
```

Using the constructor:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const B& b)
    {
        //...
    }
    int c[3];
};

class B
{
public:
    B(const A& a)
    {
        //...
    }
    int a, b, c;
};
```

What are the pros and cons of both approaches? Which should one use? And could there be some problems, if someone extended the library and used the `explicit` keyword in some of his constructors?

Comment: Use the constructor. Implicit casts are the worst. I'm yet to see a good use-case for them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Benjamin! At the moment I'm 'tending' (well, i already did it that way) to implement it as a constructor, too, but maybe there is a 'non-plus-ultra' reason, to use an implicit cast overload as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common way to perform such conversions is through the constructor. The typecast operators are used effectively only for conversions to primitive types (and then mostly to `bool` or something that effectively acts like a boolean) or types that you can't add an additional constructor to.

The typecast operators have a much bigger risk of being invoked at unexpected moments than converting constructors and should generally be treated with extreme caution.

Comment: You say typecast operators have a much bigger risk of being invoked at unexpected moments. New C++ syntax allows explicit casts. Considring this fact, is there still a reason to prefer constructor other operators?

Comment: @Silicomancer, yes. It can express the intent better to use a converting constructor.

Comment: And the syntax is much nicer: `NewType {value};` vs `static_cast<NewType>(value);`.

Answer (score 4):

One instructive example of using a type conversion operator in the Standard library is the conversion from `std::string` to `std::string_view`. Consider the simple code:

```
std::string s("string");
std::string_view sv(s);
```

No constructor of `std::string_view` accepts `std::string`, and the conversion is performed with the operator

```
operator std::string_view<...>() const noexcept;
```

in the `std::string` class.

The motivation of this design can be found in [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0254r2.pdf) (P0254R2) by Marshall Clow, which I cite below.

> When `string_view` was proposed ... the connection between `string` and `string_view` was all done in `string_view`. `string_view` has:
>
> - an implicit conversion from `string`,
> - a member function `to_string`, which creates a new string.
>
> I believe that this is backwards; that `string_view` should know nothing of `string`, and that `string` should handle the conversions between the types. Specifically, `string` should have:
>
> - an implicit conversion to `string_view`,
> - an explicit constructor from a `string_view`.
>
> **Rationale**:
>
> - `string_view` as a basic vocabulary type leads to additional efficiencies.
>
> ...
>   Creating a `string_view` from a `string` is cheap, hence the implicit conversion. Creating a `string` from a `string_view` is not cheap, so it should be explicit.
>
> - Support for other string types.
>
> ...
>   Consider outputting data from a homegrown string class ... `home_string`. Implementing `operator<<` is a fair amount of work, requiring a reasonably complete knowledge of the entire `iostream`s infrastructure. On the other hand, with `string_view`, someone could write:
>
> ```
> template<...>
> ostream<...>& operator<<(ostream<...>& os, const home_string<...>& str)
> {
>     return os << string_view<...>(str);
> }
> ```
>
> and get all the formatting, etc. "for free".